# postgis create 100 foot linestring from scratch in well known text

Tags: postgis, linestring

I am beginning to learn about postgis linear referencing functions and just generally working with lines.

I want to simply make a 100 foot line in 3424 (NJ stateplane)

first I tried creating the geometry without any SRID

```
SELECT st_length(ST_GeomFromEWKT('LINESTRING(0 0, 100 100)'))
```

I figured the 0 0 to 100 100 would be a 100 foot line?

this measures at 141.4 feet..why?

I then just simply added st_setsrid and still got the same measurement

```
SELECT st_setsrid(ST_GeomFromEWKT('LINESTRING(0 0, 100 100)'),3424) geom
```

what I am not understanding about constructing a linestring??

Comment: the length of a diagonal line 0,0 to 100,100 will be sqrt(100*100+100*100) due to pythagoras

Comment: @iant can you elaborate on this? i really want to understand this better

Comment: 0,0 to 100,100 is not a horizontal or vertical line but a diagonal across a square of 100 units per side.

Comment: okay yes now I get it after expirementing with the line and polygon creation from scratch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a diagonal line, you will want to run something like the below:

```
SELECT st_length(st_setsrid(ST_GeomFromEWKT('LINESTRING(0 0, 0 100)'),27700))
```

This will return 100m

Comment: add this to your answer via iant "0,0 to 100,100 is not a horizontal or vertical line but a diagonal across a square of 100 units per side"